# What is God's attitude or feelings towards a person who indulges in his or her bhakti, Sadhna or who just believes in them?

Tags: gods, bhakti

We often hear of them is all kind and father/mother like but I doubt it is so simple. It maybe also possible that it can't be understood by our limited human undertanding or maybe its different for different Gods.